# How to know whether someone is saluting you or not, if they say "HI" in front of you?

Tags: misunderstandings

A person says "**hi**" in front of me, but I don’t know whether the person says it to me.

There are two possibilities:

1. The person actually says "*hi*" to me.
2. The person says "*hi*" to another person behind me.

If the person actually says it to me, I should reciprocate it.
If the person says "*hi*" to another person behind me, I should do nothing.

How can I know which one is happening, when someone is saying "*hi*" in front of me.

After I know the truth, I can do the follow up action correctly.

---

I got the information from Stack Exchange Psychology & Neuroscience reply.
user287279 said that:

> If he/she say "*hi*" while he/she is looking at you, then he/she is saying "*hi*" to you. But if he/she does it while looking over your shoulder, then he/she is greeting someone else behind you.”

He/she is looking at me for a certain time, if I have not pay attention in that limited time, how can I know which one is happening.

When I hear "*hi*", I will need some time to process, There is probability that He/she is looking at me then look away.

If this happened I will not know if he/she is looking at me then looking away, or he/she don’t look at me in the first place.

Comment: `If the person say hi to another person behind me, I should do nothing to it` not necessarily true. What would be so bad about saying `Hi` to a stranger if you are not sure they talked to you? In the worst case they would look at you confused and move on

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I don't want them to look at me confused and move on. I don't want to reciprocate wrongly. I don't want they know that I reciprocate wrongly.

Comment: When the person in front of you says "hi" what are they looking at?

Comment: @DaveG The person says hi according the message I get, there is probability that they are looking at me then look away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of Type I, Type II errors. If they are saying hi to you, and you ignore them, that is one kind of error. If they are not saying hi to you and you reply, that is the other kind of error. They are different. Ignoring someone who is greeting you hurts that person's feelings. Greeting someone who was greeting someone else confuses them but is unlikely to upset them. If you have an existing relationship, ignoring them may damage that relationship. In this circumstance I would rather over-hi than snub someone who was actually talking to me, and my strategies reflect that.

Ideally you want to avoid both kinds of errors. One way is to improve the accuracy of your guess about who they are greeting. If someone says "Hi Kate" in my general direction, I think it's more likely they are greeting me than that there is another Kate behind me. And no-one will think less of me for thinking the greeting was for me. An undecorated Hi is harder to test. You can evaluate whether they are looking right at you or over your shoulder. You can compare the greeting with your relationship. "Darling! It's been ages!" from a stranger is not for you. "Finally showed up didja bud?" from someone you were talking to minutes ago is also not for you.

Ah, but you're asking about the trickiest case. All they have said is "Hi." You have several strategies available:

- always respond. Be friendly and open, and if someone wants to think less of you for it, that's about them, not you. No thinking, no deciding, just free "hi"s for anyone who might need them. This means you have zero chance of an accidental snub, even of a stranger.
- turn and look over your shoulder. If you see someone there, say nothing. If you see no-one, respond. This might confuse the person also, since it reveals you weren't sure the "hi" was for you. But it can save the burning embarrassment of greeting someone who doesn't know you or care about you.
- smile, but don't say anything. If the person is looking right at you and greeting you, they will see your smile as a response and carry on just as though you had said "hi". But if they're not looking at you and were greeting someone else, they either won't see your smile, or will interpret it as being pleased about something, possibly unrelated. It's less embarrassing.

Of the 3, I try for the first but do fall back on the third sometimes. Try it.

Comment: 4. Ask the person if they meant you if you are unsure about it. "Are you talking to me?" -> Yes/No answer and you know the result. Kind if like a mix between 1 and 2